# ESTA visa waiver program - choosing 'country where I live' while moving to another country

Tags: esta

I'm travelling to Canada soon on a 2 year working holiday visa, and have a stopover in Chicago for which I'm required to obtain a visa waiver (I'm from Ireland).

I need to enter the country where I live on the application. Should this be Ireland or Canada? Obviously writing down Ireland would be true while I fill out the application, but once I'm en route that's no longer the case since I'm heading to Canada to live there for at least 2 years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's where you live where you fill out the application.

On mine I put UK, even though a NZ citizen and had been travelling in South America for 4 months, I was returning to London.  No problems.

A year and a half later, while on my way to a Canadian working holiday (same situation as you), I stopped in Hawaii for a few days on the way (so also had a stopover in the US).  Still no problems (the ESTA is valid for 2 years), and also when asked, explained I was on my way to Canada for a working holiday.

Over the next year, I had several trips into the US, while now living in Canada.  I had to renew my ESTA, now putting Canada, but only because it'd expired.  There was no problem - the ESTA is valid for 2 years from the date of application, so it's entirely possibly you may have changed locations in that time - I've since also moved to Australia, and will be visiting the US again in two months.

*edit* a brief search shows [this came up a while back on flyertalk as well](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-issues/1315323-us-esta-new-one-required-after-change-country-residence.html) with the same result - the person had changed country, didn't need to change their ESTA, and had no problems.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that puts my mind at ease a little! I'll leave this here a while in case anyone answers with anything different. Otherwise I'll come back and accept the answer tomorrow

Comment: All good. Have fun in Canada, I was in Vancouver for a year and loved it.  From the sounds of it you're also lucky to be one of the few to get a very high-in-demand Irish visa for Canada!

Comment: Haha, yep, got my visa application in within 3 minutes, and was still number 833! :) Heading to Calgary myself, thought I'd give myself a break from rainy weather! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Wicked Hostels, small but fun, and definitely get out to Lake Louise, Jasper and Banff. Alberta is a stunning area. Enjoy!